# Default switch declaration won't make paragraph dissapear when the input value matches case

Tags: javascript, html

Well, the title might be a little bit confusing... It's hard to explain, unless I show the code.

Before bashing on me because I used `switch` instead of `if/else`, it's on a much bigger project.

So, when the user inputs an incorrect value in the `input`, I want it to display a message saying `I didn't get that, try again`. And when I input a value corresponding to the `switch` `case` element, I want that text to dissapear, and I don't know how to do it.

Jsfiddle, so you can understand it better than my POORLY written explanation.

`html`

```
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Say hi, bye or something else.">
<div id="div">
<p id="first"></p>
</div>

<p id="second"></p>
```

`css`

```
 div {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: red;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 500ms ease;
  }

 input {
 width: 250px; 
    }


 #second {
   margin-top: 225px;
   color: red;
   font-size: 32px;
   font-family: Arial;
     }
```

`javascript`

```
   var first = document.getElementById('first'),
  second = document.getElementById('second'),
  input = document.getElementById('input'),
  div = document.getElementById('div');

  function myFunction(){    
    switch(input.value){
     case 'hi':
     div.style.opacity = '1';
      break;
     case 'bye':
     div.style.opacity= '0';
     break;

     default:
     second.innerHTML = ("I didn't get that, try again.");
      break;
        }
     }

     document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey){
        if(enterKey.keyCode === 13){
        myFunction();
        input.value = '';
           }
        });
```

Here's the link to the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/eg3vmk5g/16/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do it in this way. https://jsfiddle.net/eg3vmk5g/20/

Comment: Reset everything in the beginning and proceed to your further logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the content to an empty string in front of the case part.

```
function myFunction() {
    second.innerHTML = "";
    switch (input.value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
    second = document.getElementById('second'),
    input = document.getElementById('input'),
    div = document.getElementById('div');

function myFunction() {
    second.innerHTML = "";
    switch (input.value) {
        case 'hi':
            div.style.opacity = '1';
            break;
        case 'bye':
            div.style.opacity = '0';
            break;
        default:
            second.innerHTML = "I didn't get that, try again.";
            break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey) {
    if (enterKey.keyCode === 13) {
        myFunction();
        input.value = '';
    }
});
```

```css
div { width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-color: red; opacity: 0; transition: 500ms ease; }
input { width: 250px; }
#second { margin-top: 225px; color: red; font-size: 32px; font-family: Arial; }
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Say hi, bye or something else.">
<div id="div"><p id="first"></p></div>
<p id="second"></p>
```

Comment: Dang! It was that easy?  Thanks a lot!! Though, I don't understand the logic behind it, could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding inner HTML to the DOM but if the text matches, then you are not updating the text to empty.

Here is the solution:

```
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
second = document.getElementById('second'),
input = document.getElementById('input'),
div = document.getElementById('div');

function myFunction(){    
    switch(input.value){
        case 'hi':
            second.innerHTML = ("");
          div.style.opacity = '1';
        break;
        case 'bye':
            second.innerHTML = ("");
            div.style.opacity= '0';
        break;

        default:
            second.innerHTML = ("I didn't get that, try again.");
        break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey){
    if(enterKey.keyCode === 13){
    myFunction();
    input.value = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Now that I understand how it should go,  
It is really tedious to write `second.innerHTML = (" ");` each and every time a `case` is declared. I have a huge switch element with thousands of case elements. As other people  have told me, it's easier to just declare `second.innerHTML= (" ");` before the switch declaration.

Comment: then it's better to add second.innerHTML = (" "); before switch statement and if you want to add specific messages against any cane then you can add them in that case,